# NoViableAltException found when running apache hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql

When I start hive command line I receive the following exception.

```
adminuser@adminuser-VirtualBox:~/hive-0.12.0-bin$ bin/hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/adminuser/hive-0.12.0-bin/lib/hive-common-0.12.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
NoViableAltException(287@[])
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:902)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:977)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:888)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processInitFiles(CliDriver.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:2 cannot recognize input near '~' '/' '.'
```

I was not able to locate the file `HiveParser.java` in the source to debug the error. Also when I run it as `root` user I do not get the error. But I get another exception when I execute any query

```
hive> select count(*) from preprocess_output;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="staging":adminuser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:1459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1020)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:888)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="staging":adminuser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5758)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:5731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:2469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.mkdirs(NameNode.java:911)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:1457)
    ... 28 more
Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="staging":adminuser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

I am more inclined to solve the first exception as I do not want to execute commands as 'root' unless there is no other option.

I am using Hadoop 1.2.1 and Hive 0.12.0, I have also tried Hive 0.13.1 with the same results. OS is Ubuntu 12.04. I also tried executing the commands as myself, `adminuser` and as `hive` user.

Can somebody advise a solution to this.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Seeing the same issue.

Comment: @activelearner - my apologies, I did not notice your comment but to answer, I could not resolve the exception so I did a clean reinstall of Ubuntu Linux and Hive and that worked, strangely.